# How do I perfectly center a single character inside an SVG circle?

Tags: svg

I'd like to place a single character, perfectly centered, inside this circle:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="100" height="100">
  <g>
    <circle style="fill:#eeeeee" cx="50" cy="50" r="50">
    </circle>
    <text>C</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Ideally, the solution works for any single ASCII character.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a combination of [`text-anchor="middle"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor) to centre the text horizontally, and [`dominant-baseline="central"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline) to centre it vertically.

To simplify things, I've added a `transform` attribute to your `<g>` element to move the origin to the middle of your canvas.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g transform="translate(50,50)">
    <circle style="fill:#eeeeee" r="50" />
    <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">C</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting, I had to add `y='2' style='font-size:30px;fill:white'` to make the text appear, and actually centered. Not sure why I had to bump it down by two pixels.