# Responsive design: centering text within an SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to vertically and horizontally centre a letter inside of an SVG circle so that it stays centred and stays in the same proportions with the circle. While I have the code below, I also have [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3frft2gd/1/) where if you resize the preview, then you can see the letter does not stay in proportion with the circle.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

li div {
  font-size: 60vw;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 7vw;
  left: -3vw;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="circleIcon" id="{{ item.id }}">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="46" cy="46" r="45" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="grey" />
    </svg>
    <div>I</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What can I do to keep the text in proportion with the circle without using Javascript? Thanks.

Comment: is it necessary to use the svg?

Comment: Why isn't the disc centered `cx="46" cy="46"` in the svg? The padding on the ul, can it be removed? You're using viewport sizing, so these paddings, margins, no being centered etc. complicates things.

Comment: @EnmanuelDuran Yes the SVG is required since I want to animate the shape's stroke which I cannot do through other methods.

Comment: @akinuri I wanted the SVG to scale so that it fits the size of it's container so that it grows and shrinks with it's container, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @PavSidhu Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/3frft2gd/5/). Even though it's working in this demo, you'll need to modify it to work in your actual page.

Answer (score 1):

You can horizontally centre text in SVG, but there is no perfect way to do it in the vertical direction.

Some people will suggest using `<foreignObject>` to embed a little piece of HTML in the SVG. Then take advantage of HTMLs ability to do the centering. But IMO this is overkill for simple SVGs like yours.

Another suggestion is to use `dominant-baseline` CSS property [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760693/how-do-i-perfectly-center-a-single-character-inside-an-svg-circle). But that relies on browser support for those font tables and the font having those tables.

My preferred solution is to to [use a `dy` with a value in `em` units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253766/text-align-middle-only-in-y-direction/19273331#19273331).  All you need to do is find the correct em value for the font you are using. And it will work at any font size.

For example the correct value for Verdana is around 0.36em.  Demo below.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

li div {
  font-size: 60vw;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 7vw;
  left: -3vw;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="circleIcon" id="{{ item.id }}">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="46" cy="46" r="45" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="grey" />
      <text x="46" y="46" font-family="Verdana" font-size="80" dy="0.36em" text-anchor="middle">I</text>
    </svg>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't *need* to use an svg, you can just do this by making the element circular, and giving it a border and a background color.

**Edit:** Noticed your comment about animating the border. CSS animations aren't limited to `svg`s - I've added a border color animation to my solution (learn [the basics of CSS animations at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp), and get [more in-depth on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)).

Note that this result doesn't even require more than one element. Run this snippet and scroll down to see it working with just `<div>i</div>`!

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li, div {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;

  text-align: center;

  /* the circle */
  background: gray;
  border: 1vw solid black; /* I would usually just use a px weight, but I'm trying to make it look like your example */
  border-radius: 50%; /* makes it circular */
  
  /* the letter */
  font-size: 60vw;
  line-height: 80vw; /* making the line-height the same as the parent element's height centers the letter vertically */
  
  /* animate the borders */
  -webkit-animation: pulse 5s infinite ease-in 0s;
  animation: pulse 5s infinite ease-in 0s;
}

/* the animation */
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% { border-color: black }
  50% { border-color: red }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% { border-color: black }
  50% { border-color: red }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>I</li>
</ul>

<div>i</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using an svg and take advantage of Flexbox:

**Now your html looks cleaner:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="circleIcon" id="{{ item.id }}">
        <div>I</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Here the css with some explanation of what I did:**

```
li{
  position:relative;
  list-style:none;
}

li div {
  position: relative;
  /* We center vertically and horizontally using flexbox */
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  /* until here */
  width: 100%;
  height:0;
  padding: 50% 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size:60vw;
  /* just styling the circle */
  border: 5px solid black;
  background:grey;
}
```

I added a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/3frft2gd/2/

**NOTE:** if you want the text to keep scaling you can use media queries and it'll work, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any issues with using `text` property of SVG, then this can help you out.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
li text {
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="circleIcon" id="{{ item.id }}">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="46" cy="46" r="45" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="grey" />
      <text x="45" y="45" font-family="Verdana" font-size="60" fill="black" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle">I</text>
    </svg>
  </li>
</ul>
```